# Is boost:regex block size limited?

Tags: c++, regex, boost

I have quite big text file to parse by boost:regex. To make process easier, first I decide to split big file to blocks, for future parsing each block.

I use next regex string for that:

```
FIRST1.*?FIRST2.*?FIRST3((.*?\r*\n*)*)LAST1.*?LAST2.*?LAST3
```

It allows me to receive everything I want between "FIRST1 FIRST2 FIRST3" and "LAST1 LAST2 LAST3".

Between them there exists many lines with many text (more then 20 000 bytes). And it don't works. If I split text by 2 parts (part1 ~ 10 000 bytes and part2 ~10 000 bytes), and try this regular expression with:

- FIRSTS part1 LASTS - everything parsing well
- FIRSTS part2 LASTS - everything parsing well
- FIRSTS part1part2 LASTS - breaks.

I thought it may be boost:regex limitation, and tried it here: [online regex](http://regex101.com/), it still same.

It looks like part1part2 is too big for regex block to return, is it true? Is there size limit for regex, or I just mess something up?

UPD:

I also found max size. It founds substring if it is characters [106-12131], but if I add any one character to any place of substring, it can't find it. So, it is 12025.

Comment: Are you trying to hide that you are parsing HTML/XML using regular expressions? :)

Comment: No :-) I'm trying to parse report from PBEM game. There is a lot of text and it has quite good structure. Still it is big, separated by many parts with unit's state, regions and etc.

Comment: maybe if you shared the actual file as an example...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably should not be using regex here.

I'd show you the Spirit way to do this efficiently, but you don't show relevant code, so I'll wait.

That said, at least make the groups non-capturing groups (e.g. here `((.*?\r*\n*)*)`) and consider using `cmatch` instead of `smatch` ([docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/match_results.html))

Oh, this might be a case of *catastrophic backtracking* [[¹]](http://blog.codinghorror.com/regex-performance/):

```
((.*?\r*\n*)*)
```

Try something like this:

```
(.+?[\r\n]+)*
```

Make it non-capturing too:

```
(?:.+?[\r\n]+)*
```

Comment: it don't work with +, because sometimes there are empty strings (just with \r\n), but (?:.+?[\r\n]+)* works better, and now can capture more then 12025 symbols...

Comment: The point was to avoid catastrophic backtracking. Too many nested quantifiers, especially when potentially empty, are a recipe for that. You just need to make as few things optional as possible, and always started at the most granular level (top-down).

Comment: I guess that splitting big file to small parts should be done by standart C++ std::string way (find/substr), and then use regex just with small separated parts of text where it have to be parsed.